# SQL Server Management Studio-- widen active files dropdown?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

I'm using SQL Server 2008's management studio and had a question about having multiple query windows etc open.  If I have seven or eight going at once obviously their tabs won't all fit on the screen.  But when I go to the "active files" drowpdown at the right often times the names are truncated with an ellipsis in the middle, and I can't tell which files are in the list.

Is there a UI setting or some other way to get a complete view of which queries are in which tabs?  Visual Studio 2008 has a similar feature but for some reason I can't recall any file names ever being truncated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [Tabs Studio add-in](http://www.tabsstudio.com) that has [some support for SSMS 2008](http://tabsstudio.wordpress.com/2009/10/08/tabs-studio-for-microsoft-sql-server-management-studio/).